# Phrases that would be similar to "Tip of the Iceberg" but with a positive connotation

Tags: idioms, expressions, phrase-requests

I am looking for phrases that would be similar in meaning to 'tip of the iceberg,' but has a positive connotation. My understanding is that 'tip of the iceberg' has a negative "hidden" connotation.

The phrase I am looking for is going to be used in the paragraph below:

---

> Over the last few decades, robotics research has made considerable
>   strides towards solving hard robotics problems such as navigating
>   unknown environments, recognizing and manipulating objects, and using
>   natural language to interact. These advances have resulted in some
>   interesting robotic applications, ranging from autonomous vacuum
>   cleaners and self-parking cars to personal software assistants. Yet, I
>   believe these applications are just the tip of the iceberg in a whole
>   new wave of personal robotics applications to hit the marketplace.

---

Comment: You could settle for *just the beginning of* if you don't want imagery. In context, *dawn*, or *first green shoots*, for example, are common metaphors.

Comment: On another note, I'd avoid mixing the metaphors of icebergs and waves.

Comment: I don't perceive "tip of the iceberg" as negative. But the phrase "leading edge" means something close to what you want, and combines meaningfully rather than inharmoniously with the wave metaphor.

Comment: @Peter. I agree it fits much nicer. Could you like to add it as an answer? I would like to mark your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't perceive "tip of the iceberg" as negative. However, as onomatomaniak comments, in your paragraph this metaphor mixes rather inharmoniously with the metaphor "whole new wave".

The phrase "leading edge" doesn't mean the same thing as "tip of the iceberg"; "leading edge" has a connotation of newness that "tip of the iceberg" does not. However, "leading edge" fits your intended meaning very well, and combines meaningfully with the "wave" metaphor.

Comment: Disagree about the common use of "tip of the iceberg": it is usually around bad news such as "we found out that a problem was bigger/went deeper than we first thought" (example the News International hacking scandals). The Iceberg is an analogy to the fact that only a small amount of the problem is apparent at first and when you go beneath the surface, you see the whole scale of the thing.

Answer (score 4):

How about 'only begin to scratch the surface'?

Comment: Nothing negative there (unless you're talking about CDs). Of course, the 'new wave ...' would then be incongruous.

Answer (score 3):

I believe these applications ***[herald](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/herald)*** a whole new wave of personal robotics applications.

Comment: It's a good word in many contexts, but I think OP's preceding "Yet" and "just" kinda rule out *herald* here. Which is why you discarded them in your rewrite of the sentence, obviously.

Comment: I'm a compulsive editor.

Answer (score 1):

I believe these applications are just the *forerunners* of a whole new wave of personal robotics applications.

Answer (score 1):

"Just the beginning of" is the simplest way to say it.

Answer (score -1):

I believe these applications are at the crest of a whole new wave of...

Comment: *At the crest* sounds like *at the best* or *optimal*, not *at the very beginning*.